# Set nested path on self during declaration creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, spread-syntax

just wondering if anyone knows of a good way to declare an object with a nested path that also is using spread syntax.

Here is an example that I know works:

```
const copyMe = {
    name: 'mike',
    id: '123abc456def',
    nested: {
        path: 'the old value'
    }
}

const newObject = {
    ...copyMe,
}

// Works, but adds an extra line of code.
newObject.nested.path = 'the new value'

console.log(newObject) // newObject.nested.path = 'the new value'
```

However I would like to do something like this, where I copy an entire object using spread syntax, and in the same declaration overwrite/create a path & set its value.

```
const copyMe = {
    name: 'mike',
    id: '123abc456def',
    nested: {
        path: 'the old value'
    }
}

// Syntax is incorrect. Example of what I wish to accomplish.
const newObject = {
    ...copyMe,
    ...copyMe.nested.path: 'new value here'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's `{ ...copyMe, nested: { path: '…'} }` - object literal syntax!

Comment: If you want to copy other properties from the old nested object, you'd use `{ ...copyMe, nested: { ...copyMe.nested, path: '…'} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const copyMe = {
    name: 'mike',
    id: '123abc456def',
    nested: {
        path: 'the old value'
    }
}

const newObject = {
    ...copyMe,
    nested: { ...copyMe.nested }
}
```

or

```
const copyMe = {
    name: 'mike',
    id: '123abc456def',
    nested: {
        path: 'the old value'
    }
}

const newObject = {
    ...copyMe,
    nested: {
      path: 'new value here'
    }
}
```

Comment: The `nested: ...copyMe.nested` didn't work, throws SyntaxError,  but the second option works. I assume it must require that the spread of the `...copyMe` happens before `nested: { path: 'new value'} }`